# Help needed with Subversion error

Tags: svn

I was updating a third party library and committing the new version to my SVN server. Many changes were involved (years worth). At the end of the commit, I got this message:

```
... lots of stuff ...
Commit succeeded, but other errors follow:
Error bumping revisions post-commit (details follow):
In directory 'D:\Documents and Settings\scottb\Desktop\imageen'
Error processing command 'committed' in 'D:\Documents and Settings\scottb\Desktop\imageen'
Error getting 'affected time' for 'D:\Documents and Settings\scottb\Desktop\imageen\.svn\text-base\ImageEn.cnt.svn-base'
Can't stat 'D:\Documents and 
Settings\scottb\Desktop\imageen\.svn\text-base\ImageEn.cnt.svn-base': The 
system cannot find the file specified.
```

So from the first line it appears that the commit took place. But what do the other errors mean and do I need to do something to fix them? Is the repository damaged at this point? Will I have problems in the future committing changes?

In case it matters I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.6.7 Build 18415, Subversion 1.6.9 (client) and the server is Subversion 1.6.5. I haven't had any other issues with these tools.

It's a wonderfully detailed error message with no helpful information in it.  Thanks for any insights on this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to have just been a client-side issue only and didn't affect the server. I simply deleted the directory in question and did an UPDATE command. The directory was recreated and re-downloaded and all appears to be fine now.

Comment: This worked for me as well, thank you! In my case it was also complaining during compile about an svn:externals item. I was unable to update to get the externals to copy in, and so I deleted the root and got back a fresh checkout that included all my merges.

Comment: I accidentally hit "cancel" on the Tortoise dialog after reading "operation completed" thinking it was OK to close (or words to that effect).  But the OK button was actually still grayed-out and it was hanging a little, in hindsight probably still "cleaning up" and updating my local workspace.  Heart failure averted within only minutes of palpitations beginning, as a result of this question/answer, thanks!  NB I did have to do a manual "clean up" from the workspace root in order to update the affected folder.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is related to case sensitivity of Subersion since I see *imageen* and *ImageEn* in the log.[This can be helpful.](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=2369323)

Comment: The ImageEn.cnt file was a newly added file so case sensitivity isn't likely to be a problem. Several other files did indeed have their case changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error "Can't stat {xml file}" but I had a different cause.  There was a lock by Visual Studio on my file.  When I closed Visual Studio, it released the lock on the xml file and I was able to mark the parent of this folder as deleted (got the red x icon).

Before this issue, I had went to TortoiseSVN > Delete, and deleted a huge tree of folders.  But the folder where that file lived didn't get the deleted status because Visual Studio was holding that lock.